# makefile shell grep doesn't find the file I tried to specify

Tags: makefile

This approach is not finding the file I *think* I specified.

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
PKG_NAME = test
PKG_VERSION := $(shell grep -i '^version' $(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

In the shell itself, `grep -i '^version' test/DESCRIPTION | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2` does return the version successfully, e.g. `0.4-7`

But, running via the makefile returns:

```
grep: test: Is a directory
grep: /DESCRIPTION: No such file or directory
```

`test` is a directory, that's true, but `test/DESCRIPTION` does exist, so I'm guessing `$(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION` wasn't the right way to assemble the file name.

Suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that grep is seeing `test` and `/DESCRIPTION` as two separate arguments. Do you have extra spaces on the PKG_NAME assignment line or an errant space between `$(PKG_NAME)` and `/DESCRIPTION` in the `$(shell ...)` line?

As a general rule you might want to start putting quotes around arguments to shell commands (i.e. `'$(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION'`) to prevent this sort of word splitting issue (though without spaces you generally don't have that sort of problem).

Comment: I see your point about the 2 separate arguments.  Sounds like it is not pasting the two pieces together.  However, there are no extra spaces and changing to `'$(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION'` gives the same error.

Comment: It can't possibly give the same error. Does it perhaps say `grep: 'test: Is a directory` and `grep: /DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory` or something like that? Are you sure you are running the correct makefile? What do you get if you set your SHELL to `bash -x`?

Comment: Using '$(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION' it gives: `grep: test /DESCRIPTION: No such file or directory` and there does seem to be a space in between test and the /.  Using $(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION it gives: `grep: test: Is a directory
grep: /DESCRIPTION: No such file or directory` on separate lines; setting the shell to `bash -x` doesn't seem to change anything.  Definitely seems to see a space in there, but I sure don't see it, or understand it.

Comment: A trailing space on the `PKG_NAME = test` line will do it.

Comment: I had checked for that trailing space, it wasn't visible, but there was something foul there, a bad EOL or something, as retyping it cleared it out.  Thank you very much!